# Unexpected. Please try again, error message

Tags: google-bigquery

Trying to import a 2.8GB of file via GS to Big query, and the job failed with:

```
Unexpected. Please try again.
```

here are some other outputs

```
Job ID: aerobic-forge-504:job_a6H1vqkuNFf-cJfAn544yy0MfxA
Start Time: 5:12pm, 3 Jul 2014
End Time: 7:12pm, 3 Jul 2014
Destination Table: aerobic-forge-504:wr_dev.phone_numbers
Source URI: gs://fls_csv_files/2014-6-11_Global_0A43E3B1-2E4A-4CA9-BD2A-012B4D0E4C69.txt
Source Format: CSV
Allow Quoted Newlines: true
Allow Jagged Rows: true
Ignore Unknown Values: true
Schema:
area: INTEGER
number: INTEGER
```

Comment: Does it have a header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The job failed due to timeout; there is a maximum of 2 hours allowed for processing; after that the import job is killed.  I'm not sure why the import was so slow; from what I can tell we only processed at about 100KB/sec, which is far slower than expected. It is quite possible that the error is transient.

In the future, you can speed up the import by setting allow_quoted_newlines to false, which will allow bigquery to process the import in parallel. Alternately, you can partition the file yourself and send multiple file paths in the job.

Can you try again and let us know whether it works?